# Display label before UIWebView loads

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, uitabbar

When my app launches, the first thing the user is presented with is a web view in a `UITabBar`. Unfortunately, until the web page loads, they stare at a blank white screen minus the `UITabBar`. How would I hide a label once the web page loads?

firstviewcontroller.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webPage;
```

firstviewcontroller.m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *fullURL = @"http://example.com";
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fullURL];
    NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [_webPage loadRequest:requestObj];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the UIWebView delegate method webViewDidFinishLoad:. This will be called after the page loads, and then you can remove the label from its superview or set its hidden property to YES.